# Give link with href in mail - rails4

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, email, outlook

Here I used job and service to send a mail to users. Now I want to send our app link with mail as a play store image. I totally done with gmail account. But for a outlook users, the image does not display. What I was done is, **in mailer**

```
def course_mailer(email, title, description)
mail(:bcc => email, :subject => title) do |format|
  format.html { render html: '<div class="text-center" style="margin-top: 60px;">'
                         "#{description}" '<br>
                        <a href="https://play.google.com/store..." target="blank">
                          <img alt="Get it on Google Play" src="https://play.google.com/intl/en_us/badges/images/generic/en_badge_web_generic.png" style="height: 75px;"></a>
                        </div>'.html_safe }
end
```

I call this method in my service as,

```
CourseMailer.course_mailer(@delivery[0].emailIds, @delivery[0].title, @delivery[0].description).deliver_now!
```

This service correctly called when a mail send to gamil domain. The image source doesnot display when the mail sent to outlook users. The change done in html is,
**in gmail,**

```
<img alt="Get it on Google Play" src="https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/SIiw9QYZvvWkjPnHXXOtNDZOQSVfteW0xFkeVVgT--Mz5VwUkdd1Cy64y5G9geRByBkoHWsDjnWXg5apnUVsQgykWcnVZKHCCU44Us1cjWtNfibbBrzOl3XO3FLu8fn8dGmE0tJnqA=s0-d-e1-ft#https://play.google.com/intl/en_us/badges/images/generic/en_badge_web_generic.png" style="height:75px" class="CToWUd">
```

**in outlook,**

```
<img alt="Get it on Google Play" style="height:75px" blockedimagesrc="https://play.google.com/intl/en_us/badges/images/generic/en_badge_web_generic.png">
```

The **img src**(gmail) changed into image **blockedimagesrc**(outlook).How can I get the img src to display an image in outlook also.

Answer (score 0):

> Images are blocked by default except for trusted senders. When images
> are blocked, there are two options displayed at the top of the email:
>
> “To help protect your privacy, some content in this message has been
> blocked. To re-enable the blocked features, click here.”
>
> “To always show content from this sender, click here.”
>
> When either option is selected, images display. If you choose to “always show content from
> this sender,” images will automatically display from that sender
> moving forward.

Source: https://litmus.com/blog/rendering-css-support-more-in-office-365s-outlook-web-app

Comment: Okay. Then for every time, I want to give re-enable the blocked option Or If once I click the option, there is no need to come again this click??? .